# Can't import MultiOutputMixin in Linear Regression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I was trying to run the linear regression model that is given in chapter 2 of Machine Learning with Scikit Learn and Tensorflow by A Geron. But I am getting this `Can't import MultiOutputMixin error`.

Can someone help me out with that. I have written my code in Azure Notebooks(its basically a jupiter notebook)

Here is the code:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression,MultiOutputMixin
from sklearn.linear_model.base import MultiOutputMixin

lin_reg=LinearRegression()

lin_reg.fit(housing_prepared,housing_labels)
```

Error:

```
_ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
----> 1 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression,MultiOutputMixin
2 from sklearn.linear_model.base import MultiOutputMixin
3
4 lin_reg=LinearRegression()
5

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/init.py in
10 # complete documentation.
11
---> 12 from .base import LinearRegression
13
14 from .bayes import BayesianRidge, ARDRegression

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py in
25
26 from ..utils._joblib import Parallel, delayed
---> 27 from ..base import (BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin, RegressorMixin,
28 MultiOutputMixin)
29 from ..utils import check_array, check_X_y

ImportError: cannot import name 'MultiOutputMixin'_
```

Comment: I don' think you should import `MultiOutputMixin`. Can you make sure to update your sklearn installation to the current revsion and maybe restart jupyter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Stef. I have included '''import MultiOutputNixin''' because I was getting the same error ImportError: cannot import name 'MultiOutputMixin'_. Yeah I have restarted the kernel and now its working.